# as3 change all button colors

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-cs5, flash-cs6

I am trying to replace the color of all buttons called 'myButtons' using this code:

```
        colorTransform.color = 0xaf4b44;
        myButtons.transform.colorTransform = colorTransform;
```

but only the most recently created button is changing color, and not all of them.
They are all called myButtons. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: You should reassign the whole **transform** property, changing its fields only does not trigger anything. Yes, that's how it is. Yes, confusing.

Comment: how would I reassign the whole transform property?

Comment: I took a bit of reading, it should work as it is. You need to assign **colorTransform** to each object by the object's reference then. Your code should change the color of a single object.

Comment: You will probably need to store the references to all buttons and then change the color on each of them. The code part where you create your buttons might help :)

Answer (score 0):

If all the buttons have the same parent you can use the following code. I would advise you to use different name for each button though.

```
var colorTransform:ColorTransform=new ColorTransform;
colorTransform.color = 0xaf4b44;

var mc:MovieClip=new MovieClip;
mc=root["myButtons"].parent;

for(var i:int=0; i<mc.numChildren; i++){
    if(mc.getChildAt(i).name=="myButtons"){
        mc.getChildAt(i).transform.colorTransform = colorTransform;
    }
}
```